# Parsing command output in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to parse the output of `docker node ls -f name=manager`.

On bash prompt this is how it looks

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY
kdrdpvwlbwai6626u640sotnh *   manager             Ready               Active
```

I want to print an error message if the `STATUS` is not Read i.e. if in grep the match is not found for the word "Ready".

I tried but the command `docker node ls -f name=manager` due to spaces and arguments is treated as more than one command in the script for some reason.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The conventional method of doing this would be

```
#docker command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Docker error"
fi
```

**Edit**

Supposing you get two lines of output, below would do

```
count=$(docker node ls -f name=manager | tail -n 1 | grep -c 'Ready[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*$')
if [ $count -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Docker Error"
fi
```

Comment: that is not my Q. I am not trying to read the status of the command, i am trying to parse the output of the command

Comment: @curiousengineer : I know but I'm pretty sure `docker` would give you a non-zero exit status for anything other than `READY`. However, I have put another solution that suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bash recognizes array values as separated by blank characters. 
It hold a variable called `IFS` with the separator, and in case you want to change it, you have to change this variable.
The regular process is: storing the old value of this var, change it, process the data and restore it:

```
OFS=$IFS
# for new line there is special var: $'\n'
IFS=$'\n'
#your code here
IFS=$OFS
```

SO you can change the IFS, read the whole lines as one value and than process it with substitution: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Another option is using `awk` (this command will print host and status):

```
docker node ls -f name=manager | awk '{print $2, $3}'
```

**OR refine you search and get the hosts that status is not ready:**

```
docker node ls -f name=manager | awk -F' '{if ($3 != "Ready") print $2}'
```

In case you have only one host, you can use grep to print if it found or not:

```
docker node ls -f name=manager | grep -iq "not ready" && echo "Not found" || echo "Found"
```

or omit the `||echo "Found"` if you want to print an error message only

Comment: hi tamar, thanks, i just want to print "found" if the word "Ready" is present or print "not found".

Comment: for each line or for all the output?

Comment: @curiousengineer Your `awk` solution may not work because there is no correspondence, when it comes to the number of fields, if you look at line one and line2. See a rogue `*` in line2?

Comment: @curiousengineer - I added a line with grep.